# How to get only selected column in a child related model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I have two models, **`User`** and **`Post`**, where a **`User`** can have multiple **`Post`** models. In my application, I only want to retrieve the **`title`** column from the related **`Post`** model when querying for a **`User`**. Here is my current code:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried to retrieve the **`title`** column for the related **`Post`** models:

```
$user = User::with('posts:title')-\>get();
```

However, this retrieves all the columns for the **`Post`** model. How can I modify my code to only retrieve the **`title`** column for the related **`Post`** models? Thank you!

Comment: you can't only select the `title` column; you also need to select the foreign key, `user_id`, on `posts` so Eloquent can match up the children, posts, to their parents, users ... the fact that you are getting all of the columns is odd, can you show the code you have after this `get` call that shows you are getting all columns?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The code that comes after the `get()` call is:

$posts = $user->posts;

This line of code retrieves all columns for the related `Post` models, even though I used `with('posts:title')` in my original query. Is there a way to modify this line of code to only retrieve the `title` column for the related `Post` models? Thank you.

Comment: that line would throw an error as the Eloquent Collection, `$user`, does not have a property named `posts` ... the Models contained in the Collection might have that property though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $user = User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
                      $query->select('title');
              }])->get();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This solution looks elegant but the `with` method only accepts strings, perhaps only on the latest version.  Instead, use it this way: `User::with('posts:title,user_id')->get()` as per @japs answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the data with selected column you also need to pass the `FK` to identify its relationship.

The example below tells the the post also need the `user_id` column to identify the relationship between `POST` and `USER` model

```php
$user = User::with('posts:title,user_id')->get();
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me, I had to pass the FK to identify it's relationship before it could work